# Do I need to be a fast typer/power user to start using Vim?

Tags: habit-breaking

I started learning serious programming since last year. Over the course, I have used various GUI based text editors and IDEs and, I decided to settle with **Sublime Text** a few months ago. Now I want to switch to a text based editor either Vim or Emacs, most probably Vim. But I am not a particularly fast typer. I am not a total noob but I wouldn't say I am a super user either. According to everything I have learned so far about Vim, you really need to be a power user to start using it but I am thinking about spending a few weeks for learning Vim along with continuing learning as I go.

Is this the right path or should I wait and master important coding and typing skills first, be comfortable and then think about it?

Answer (score 2):

Many will tell you that you need good typing skills to use Vim, since (almost) all your interactions with it are on the keyboard.

However, I think that Vim is uniquely well suited to people who *don't* type well, since once you are fluent in it, you can do so much with so few keystrokes: even hunt-and-peck-typists gain from Vim's modal interface.

This is not an entirely theoretical viewpoint: I've on occasion used Vim with my iPhone's software keyboard to write reasonable sized chunks of code.

Whether it's a good idea to learn Vim while you are still learning programming is another issue. While I believe Vim's learning curve is less steep than generally purported, it does still exist, and any brain cycles you are spending on your editor are ones you're *not* spending on your code, so it might arguably be better to wait until you're comfortable in your chosen programming language(s) before attempting to use Vim in that area.

If you intend to treat Vim as a side-hobby though, rather than something you're doing at the *same time* as learning programming, then sure, why not! [Vim is fun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781607/328936)!

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to be a super fast power typer. You might become one though if you get hooked to it!

I'd suggest you to run the command:

```
vimtutor
```

in your terminal, go through the tutorial, and after a few lessons, you will quickly see how you feel about it.

Comment: Can I know why the -1?